# Not able to install the nginx-ingress on azure kubernetes cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, devops, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I am trying to install the ingress on a new azure kuberenetes cluster but it is giving following error:-

```
helm install germanyingress  ingress-nginx --namespace test --set controller.replicaCount=2 --set controller.scope.enabled=true --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="*******" --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"="true"
WARNING: "kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com" is deprecated for "stable" and will be deleted Nov. 13, 2020.
WARNING: You should switch to "https://charts.helm.sh/stable"
Error: failed to download "ingress-nginx" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

I already tried many ways but no luck.

Comment: As per the warning message, that repo is deprecated and many of the charts that were there have been moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message is very clear, you're using a Helm repo that is deprecated.

Remove it using

```
helm repo remove germanyingress
```

Add the Kubernetes one

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update
```

or the one from Nginx

```
helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
helm repo update
```